# Characterizing strong connectedness

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove a directed graph $G$ is strongly connected iff each nonempty subset $U\subset V$ has at least one edge going from it to $U^c$.

I started trying to construct this path with a bunch of choices and recursions but I feel I'm really missing the point and that a proof should be two lines in each direction. What should I be doing?

Comment: the graphs are finite right?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo yep, they're all finite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is is strongly connected then any proper subset $U\subseteq V$ is not a connected component, and so there must exist an edge from $U$ to $U^c$.

Conversely, build the directed graph $G'$ in which the vertices are the connected components of $G$ and there is an edge from $c_1$ to $c_2$ if and only if there is an edge from a vertex of component $c_1$ to a vertex of component $c_2$ in $G$. Note that $G'$ must be a directed acyclic graph. Therefore there most be a vertex in $G'$ with out-degree $0$, let $c$ be the vertex with out-degree $0$.

Notice that if $c$ is not all of $G$ then the subset $c\subseteq V$ has no edges from $c$ to its complement, we conclude that if $G$ satisfies that for every proper subset $U\subseteq V$ there is an edge from $U$ to $U^c$ then $G$ is strongly connected.